# Get unique values in two columns at the same time (not unique combination)

Tags: r, unique, distinct

I have a data frame like this:
`dat <- data.frame(x1 = c(1,2,2,3,3,4,5), x2 = c("a","a","b","c","d","e","e"))`.
My desired output is to keep the rows that have unique values in column X1 and also have unique values in column X2 at the same time AND keep as many unique values in column x1 as possible. For example, the desired output could be `data.frame(x1=c(1,2,3,4), x2=c("a","b","c","e"))` or `data.frame(x1=c(1,2,3,5), x2=c("a","b","c","e"))`. I'm okay with any one of these two outputs.

Hope to get your advice. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try with `duplicated` `subset(subset(dat, !duplicated(x2)), !duplicated(x1))`.  If there are more columns, use `out <- dat;
for(nm in rev(names(dat))) out <- out[!duplicated(out[[nm]]),]`

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, akrun! If I input more records in the data frame to make  it like ```dat <- data.frame(x1 = c(1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,8,9,10), x2 = c('a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'i', 'i'))``` and use your code with ```subset```, I will get ```data.frame(x1=c(1,2,3,4,6,7,8), x2=c("a","b","c","e","f","g","h"))```, but my desired output should be ```data.frame(x1=c(1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9), x2=c("a","b","c","e","f","g","h","i"))```. Could you give my any advice to do that? Thanks!